# Prove if $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {x_{nk}} = l$ for some $l \in R$, then$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {x_{n}} = l$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

Hi folks I know that I should probably be using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and the definition of a Cauchy sequence, but I am not really sure where to get started.

Let $(x_n)$ be Cauchy Sequence and let $(x_{nk})$ be a subsequence such that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {x_{nk}} = l$  for some $l \in R$, prove $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {x_{n}} = l$.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're allowed to assume? If a sequence is Cauchy it has a unique limit. All subsequences must converge to this limit.

Comment: yeah thats right, thats why this questions not really making sense to me. I guess maybe they want you to show that other using words @DavidPeterson

Comment: the idea is that you want show $x_n$ get close to $l$ as $n$ becomes large, but you already know $x_n$ will be close with $x_{n_k}$ for being Cauchy and $x_{n_k}$ is close to $l$ by assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given, there is $N_1 > 0$ such that: $|x_n - x_m| < \varepsilon/2$ when $m, n > N_1$. Since $n > N_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $n_k > N_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x_n - x_{n_k}| < \varepsilon/2$ . Also there is $N_2 > 0$ such that $|x_{n_k} - L| < \varepsilon/2$  if $n > N_2$. Choose $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ then if $n > N$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x(n) - L| < |x_n - x_{n_k}| + |x_{n_k} - L| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon$.

Comment: I have edited your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: BTW Shouldn't you use $k>N_2$ where working with the subsequence? Saying: _there is $N_2 > 0$ such that $|x_{n_k} - L| < \varepsilon/2$ if_ $n > N_2$ does not look correct, since there is no variable denoted by $n$. (Maybe $n_k>N_2$? This would make sense, too.)